# Check in Cocoa if a MountPath Partition is bootable

Tags: cocoa, boot

I want to check that you can boot from a volume… Like the System Pref for Start Volume does.
Any ideas?
I looked in a lot of Tables, but nothing that indicates that is bootable.
On Linux you can use fdisk -l but that won't work on Mac OS.

Answer (score 1):

```
diskutil info -plist (path)
```

With the `-plist` option the results include a boolean flag named `Bootable`.